# Root cause of Postgres database corruption

Tags: postgresql, windows

I've been suffering from occasional (but regular) database corruption recently. Errors like this.

```
compressed lz4 data is corrupt
```

and

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlException:
invalid page in block 1787279 of relation pg_tblspc/16402/PG_14_202107181/16404/187394
Severity: ERROR
Code: XX001
```

also

```
could not access status of transaction nnnnnnnn
```

The normal fix (for me) seems to be drop and re-create the object.

Now can I investigate the root cause?

The operating system (windows) seems to be behaving itself, chkdsk and various other tools all claim the disk is fine, so my suspicions are leaning towards postgres itself. One of the issues is that the corruption is occasionally happening on tables containing recent data - before nightly backups have taken place. The DB operates 24/7 and the corruption is happening maybe once a week, no recent power outages or failures.

Update - can anyone voting to close please add a comment explaining reason. Thank you.

Comment: Strongly recommend you contact the Postgres developers directly and ask them for assistance in locating the cause.

Comment: @Colin 't Hart - how do I do that? thanks

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/account/submitbug/ But it's unlikely that we can help. Errors when reading data do not help to find what happened when writing. The fact that the errors are different (and we don't get a lot of bug reports about them) indicates a problem outside the database. Check RAM via memtest (even if it's ECC)

Comment: What tool are you using to backup? I'm going to VtC for the moment - but maybe this can go somewhere?

Comment: @Verace - I use pg_dump for backups. Why do you ask? the corruption is manifesting itself before i get around to backing up the table.

Comment: You say that this happens once a  week - I was just wondering if you restored once a week and maybe it was this that was causing your issues? But it would appear not. I've been on this site for a few years now and I can't recall seeing another issue of block corruption.

Comment: A search here `[postgresql] block corruption` gives 17 results and many of those are just discussing various issues around it - not like you "I've got block corruption" (paraphrase). Only 1 result for ` "invalid page in block"` and 0 for the `compressed lz4 data is corrupt`, but it's a new feature so no surprise. Not saying your wrong, just that there appear to be so few issues of this nature that I'd suspect either my OS or my hardware. Any chance you can change disk(s) array? What is your hardware configuration BTW?